# Android stopwatch shows wrong minutes value

Tags: android, timer, stopwatch

I'm making somekind of stopwatch and with this code i'm calculating elapsed time:

```
int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (millis%1000);
int hours = minutes / 60;
labelTime.setText(String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d",seconds)+ ":" + String.format("%03d",milliseconds));
```

This works, but after 1 hour my stopwatch shows for example 01:61:22 instead of 01:01:22.
How to start minutes from 0?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just use something like:

```
if(minutes>59){
minutes = 0;
}
```

Comment: should be `if(minutes>59)`. We don't want to see 60 in a clock.

Answer (score 2):

```
labelTime.setText(String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes-(hours*60)) + ":" + String.format("%02d",seconds)+ ":" + String.format("%03d",milliseconds));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you what you are expecting

```
if(minutes > 59){
    minutes = 60 - minutes;
    hours = hours + 1;
}
```